# What is value for eddy coefficient for N87 ferrite material

Tags: transformer, power-electronics

I have gone through many articles and papers but did not found the ferrite eddy current coefficient so that I can find out eddy current losses.  If anybody knows this it will be very helpful, there is also one more question: the volume and thickness given in \$P_\textrm{eddy} = {K_e} f^2 {B_\textrm{max}}^2 t^2 V\$ (where V is volume, t is thickness) but I do not know of what volume and thickness should I consider.

Ref:

[image]

comes from: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/hysteresis-loss-and-eddy-current-loss

Comment: So what is your motivation here -- is it to solve for eddy current specifically, or do you just need to know core losses? Because there is an easier and better documented method to solve the latter.  The reference appears to be relating to laminated silicon steel (mains frequency) application only, and I don't know that the exponents given are even representative in that case.

Comment: Eddy current losses in ferrites are always negligible as far as I'm aware; ferrites have very high resistivity. Hysteresis losses dominate by a very wide margin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the \$K_e\$ that you are missing, is \$\frac{\pi^2}{6 \rho}\$.  See:
[Core loss models in electrical steel sheets with different
orientation | PRZEGLĄD ELEKTROTECHNICZNY](http://pe.org.pl/articles/2011/9b/8.pdf) eq. (4).  Whether that gives meaningful results, or there's another material property coefficient missing, I don't know.

This article's list of references looks promising as further reading.

Note that most of the article is concerned with electrical steel, i.e. low frequency transformers, mostly mains frequency.  These are ordinary conductors -- metals -- so eddy currents are quite significant in them, and both eddy current and hysteresis losses should be accounted for in the loss calculation.

Also note that ferromagnetism is a notoriously impenetrable physical phenomenon, mostly worked with through convenient empirical approximations.  We must not lose sight of where those approximations are applicable, and we must be careful to test the applicability of any particular result to other conditions.

Case in point: electrical steel is widely rated in loss per mass, making several assumptions at once: the thickness, flux density and frequency are all nominal (50/60Hz application, just below saturation), and the shape and dimensions of the transformer aren't very important -- so much so in fact that transformer cores are often weighted rather than dimensioned, hence the mass figure.  (Given these assumptions, the mass of a transformer does track very closely with its VA capacity, given typical materials, geometry, and construction methods.)

For our purposes, the B<sup>1.6</sup> exponent doesn't appear to extend beyond steel; but the generalized Steinmetz form \$p_c = C_m f^\alpha B^\beta\$ seems to still do well enough for ferrites, with α near 1 and β typically 2-3.  See: [Steinmetz's_equation | Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steinmetz%27s_equation)  Exact values must be fitted to the core loss plots provided by the manufacturer.

I did a curve fit on TDK N97 myself, which gave best results for a further modified form, \$p_c = C_m \left(f^\alpha + C_{m1} f^{\alpha_1} \right) B^\beta\$, with β around 2.3; α, 1.1; and α<sub>1</sub>, 2.5.  (Perhaps this is hint of a f<sup>2</sup>B<sup>2</sup> (eddy current) term, perhaps not.)

I don't have data on N87 specifically, unfortunately.  The [datasheet](https://www.tdk-electronics.tdk.com/download/528882/990c299b916e9f3eb7e44ad563b7f0b9/pdf-n87.pdf) is readily obtained from the manufacturer.

If you are solving for losses, eddy currents are generally not significant in ferrite.  The resistivity is much higher than metals: [TDK N97](https://www.tdk-electronics.tdk.com/download/528886/f7953b4caf14b9c4a15e34b60fb09812/pdf-n97.pdf), a MnZn ferrite, is about 8Ωm.  This gives a skin depth of on the order of 100mm at 100kHz, negligible for most applications.  (Very large transformers, say 100kVA and up, are constructed of ferrite bricks glued together; partly because core shapes simply aren't manufactured in such sizes, but this conveniently also solves the eddy current issue.)

NiZn ferrites are also in common use for electronics, and are typically about a million times more resistive; their downsides are lower saturation flux density and permeability, so are mostly used at radio frequencies.